# has_many :through :: HasManyThroughOrderError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have problem with ActiveRecords and has_many with class_name.

I have these models:

**main_transaction.rb**

```
class MainTransaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :supplier, :class_name => 'Company'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'Company'

  has_many :invoices

end
```

**invoice.rb**

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :main_transaction
    has_one :recipient, :through => :main_transaction, source: :company
end
```

**company.rb**

```
class Company
    has_many :main_transactions
    has_many :invoices, through: :main_transactions
end
```

And problem is, when I do this select in invoice model:

```
def self.company_filter(companies)
        joins(:main_transaction, :recipient).where("companies.company_name IN (?)", companies )
end
```

The error is:

```
Could not find the source association(s) :company in model MainTransaction. Try 'has_many :recipient, :through => :main_transaction, :source => <name>'. Is it one of supplier, recipient, invoices, main_transaction_elements, or main_transaction_attachments?
```

I tried many combinations, but still doesn't work...

Comment: Hi @rails_dev, Could you show me the output of this: `Invoice.joins(:recipient).to_sql`?

Comment: I get the same error if i call this method.

Answer (score 0):

You specified `:source` incorrectly in the `has_one :recipient` in your `Invoice` model. You need to change from `:company` to `:recipient`:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :main_transaction
  has_one :recipient, :through => :main_transaction, source: :recipient
end
```

Comment: Now, the error is:
'Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Invoice#recipient' which goes through 'Invoice#main_transaction' before the through association is defined.'

Comment: Could you show me the output of this: Invoice.joins(:main_transaction).to_sql

Comment: SELECT `invoices`.* FROM `invoices` INNER JOIN `main_transactions` ON `main_transactions`.`id` = `invoices`.`main_transaction_id`

Comment: How about this one: `Invoice.joins(main_transaction: :recipient)`?

Comment: This causes an error:
Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Invoice#recipient' which goes through 'Invoice#main_transaction' before the through association is defined.

Comment: Are you sure your model `MainTransaction` is defined correctly? Try to call this one: `MainTransaction.joins(:recipient)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may not be forced to specify any source on your `has_one` association between `Invoice` and `MainTransaction`.

As of your code current state, ActiveRecord is trying to look for a `company` association on `MainTransaction`, because you force it to, with the `source` option you use.

But the `has_one :recipient` association on `Invoice` already has an existing counterpart, named the same way, on `MainTransaction`.

What happens if you simply remove the `source: :company` from `Invoice`?

Comment: I tried this too..
If I delete this, the error is:
'Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Invoice#recipient' which goes through 'Invoice#main_transaction' before the through association is defined.'